# Parity not downloading/syncing beyond block 2361658

Tags: synchronization, parity

I'm running Parity 1.3.2 and everything is fine until I get to block 2361658 and then it just doesn't go beyond that. Looks like I have 0 peers as well. Is this the "attack block"? It has been running for several hours and it still is stuck at this block. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I am running Parity 1.3.6 and the sync stopped at block 2394668 and 2385824 resp (two different Ubuntu systems). Parity uses 80% of memory and virtually no CPU. I wilt attempt to restart - maybe this will get it moving?

Comment: yes this is due to the attacks. sync will be very slow for a couple of thousend blocks. It should be better after 2463000.

Comment: As your blockchain was built using Parity < 1.3.8, if after upgrading to >= 1.3.8 and your chain still does not sync, try removing your old chain data so that Parity can resync from the start.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [hard fork](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/10/18/faq-upcoming-ethereum-hard-fork/) recently and you have to upgrade parity to at least version 1.3.8.

The latest parity is 1.3.9, so [upgrade as soon as possible](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/releases).